# 'whenever you are available in your time zone' is correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm discussing business with my partner who lives in a different country and with a big gap of time difference.  My morning time is his evening time and vice versa. I want to leave my questions on his Skype whenever they come across my mind, but try to be polite letting him know that he can just get back to me whenever he is available/convenient. Can I say:

> whenever you are available in your time zone

Comment: It's fine as is, but we are not supposed to do editing here. :)

Comment: Is there some other time zone in which they would be available?

Answer (score 2):

You might just say "Reply when convenient." Your partner must already know you are in different time zones.

The phrase "whenever you are available in your time zone" sounds as if the partner is traveling through time zones.

Answer (score 1):

Just say, *Whenever you are available.*

I do the same thing once in a while.  Remind the other party that you are aware of the time difference. That might also help them if they might not be aware.

> So, it is 6:20 in the morning there in Hong Kong and 5:20 here in Bangkok. Please
> call me whenever you are available.  I plan to call you at 7:00
> tomorrow morning, your time, no matter what.